# Absolutely positioned element margins move other elements

Tags: css, margin

I need to animate the margin of form inputs without affecting any other element's positions. So I gave all the inputs `position: absolute` for all of the inputs in the form.
However, this has created a problem for me: all of the inputs stick close together and if add a `margin-top: 40px` to them it affects all of the inputs as one element rather than spacing them out individualy.

**How do I space out all the input elements individually?**

Comment: lets see an example in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: For starters you need to show an example and besides that, if your using a positioned element you should not use `margins`. Use `top, left, bottom, and right` to position the `absolute` element around.

Comment: You probably want to position the elements within their wrappers, not the whole page, so set the parent of the element to position:relative. You need to show your HTML + CSS for more detailed answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are positioned absolutely, use their positions to space them out.

Any margin you add simply makes each element bigger, it doesn't affect the actually position of the element.

Note that you might be able to make things easier for yourself by wrapping your elements in a DIV and then animating the position of the entire DIV at once. But then as commentators above said, we're not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like position: relative would be a better solution to modifying the margin of a form input without affecting anything else. Absolute takes it out of the flow, but using relative you can move elements without having an effect on other elements.